# Cannot install Purchase Management Module

Tags: odoo

I am running openERP 7 on windows 7 pro, and I want to install Purchase Management module. 
But when I install the Purchase module, the module that is installed not Purchase module but Warehouse module and the status of the Purchase management module is not yet installed.

How can I install Purchase Management Module properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information about this, maybe u've an error in your system, but i want to let you know that the purchase module will install the warehouse module or update it as there is a dependancy btw them

Comment: Hi, yesterday I made a mistake, when I installed Purchase module was not in "Apps" menu, but in "Installed Modules" which is I was not have the addon Purchase already to installed actually. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall OpenERP, postgres reinstall again and install the warehouse management from apps which install purchase management automatically.